# Passing variable to Google Maps Event object. (Google Maps Polygon, external element hover)

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to pass a hover event to the google maps v3 api, google.maps.event object.
The goal I'm trying to achieve is trigger a hover  effect (mouseenter/mouseout) of an external element using jQuery.

Below is the code I'm using, trying to access the polygon then change it's opacity via the external element hover.

```
        $(".element-to-hover").mouseover(function(){
            $(this).addClass("active-hover");
            google.maps.event.addListener($(this).attr("id"),"mouseover",function(){
                this.setOptions({fillOpacity: "1"});
            }); 
        });
```

However, every time I utilize this method, I'm returned with the following error. "TypeError: c is undefined"

I'm unable to find a suitable solution using the GMv3API documentation.

// Edit

Below is a minimized snippet if the map function I'm using.

```
function initialize() {
        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(45.509399, -73.631484);
            var mapOptions = {
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                styles: [{"featureType":"administrative","elementType":"labels.text.fill","stylers":[{"color":"#444444"}]},{"featureType":"landscape","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"color":"#f2f2f2"}]},{"featureType":"poi","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"road","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"saturation":-100},{"lightness":45}]},{"featureType":"road.highway","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"visibility":"simplified"}]},{"featureType":"road.highway","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"visibility":"on"},{"saturation":"0"},{"lightness":"-17"}]},{"featureType":"road.arterial","elementType":"labels.icon","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"transit","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"water","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"color":"#171f4a"},{"visibility":"on"}]}],
                center: latlng,
                zoom: 12,
            }   

            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('googleMappingContainer'), mapOptions);
                var griffintownSpec = [
                    {lat: 45.498276, lng: -73.561388},
                    {lat: 45.490125, lng: -73.567316},
                    {lat: 45.485214, lng: -73.566365},
                    {lat: 45.492362, lng: -73.553377},
                    {lat: 45.494958, lng: -73.554621},
                    {lat: 45.495638, lng: -73.555167},
                    {lat: 45.496127, lng: -73.556017},
                    {lat: 45.498276, lng: -73.561388}
                ];
                var griffintown = new google.maps.Polygon({
                    paths: griffintownSpec,
                    strokeColor: '#ffffff',
                    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
                    strokeWeight: 1,
                    fillColor: '#7FAFCB',
                    fillOpacity: 0.80
                });
                griffintown.setMap(map);
        }
        function codeAddress() {
            geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: results[0].geometry.location,
                    map: map
                });

            } else {
                alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);

            }
        });

    }
```

I wish to be able to, on hover, pass the defined variable mentioned above to the Google google.maps.event object.

//Edit: added URL of site in question.
http://pwmhosting.ca/alm/find-your-office/

//Edit: Added Html of hover element

```
<div class="row">
<div class="control-selector-group">
    <div class="control-selector-location">
        <div class="selector-title"><h2>Burroughs</h2></div>
        <div class="element-to-hover" id="griffintown">GRIIFFINTOWN/div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please explain reasoning for down voting post.

Comment: The first argument of the `addListener` method needs to be a google.maps.Polygon object, not whatever `$(this).attr("id")` returns.

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified that. The id is added using PHP in WordPress. The polygon is determined in the initialization of the function prior to the page being loaded. Then an element with the same ID is then generated from that specific post, subsequently returning the same object name.

Comment: Is it a `google.maps.Polygon` object? I wouldn't expect it to be.  Please clarify that in your question and provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: I've made an update but I think perhaps my lack of knowledge of this API is coming into play >_>

Comment: Where/how is the mouseover code used in the snippet you provided?  I would think there would need to be some HTML to reproduce the issue, what does that look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion is to make a global `polygons` array, indexed by the `id` of the polygon.

```
// in the global scope
var polygons = [];
```

Then:

```
// Construct the polygon.
var cartierville = new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: cartiervilleSpec,
    strokeColor: '#ffffff',
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 1,
    fillColor: '#DC3B35',
    fillOpacity: 0.80
});
cartierville.setMap(map);

// add it to the global array
polygons["cartierville"] = cartierville;
google.maps.event.addListener(cartierville, "mouseover", function () {
    this.setOptions({
        fillOpacity: "1"
    });
    $("#cartierville").addClass("active-hover");
});
google.maps.event.addListener(cartierville, "mouseout", function () {
    this.setOptions({
        fillOpacity: "0.80"
    });
    $("#cartierville").removeClass("active-hover");
});

var griffintown = new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: griffintownSpec,
    strokeColor: '#ffffff',
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 1,
    fillColor: '#7FAFCB',
    fillOpacity: 0.80
});
griffintown.setMap(map);

// add it to the global array
polygons["griffintown"] = griffintown;
google.maps.event.addListener(griffintown, "mouseover", function () {
    this.setOptions({
        fillOpacity: 1
    });
    $("#griffintown").addClass("active-hover");
});
google.maps.event.addListener(griffintown, "mouseout", function () {
    this.setOptions({
        fillOpacity: 0.80
    });
    $("#griffintown").removeClass("active-hover");
});
```

Then you can add the mouseover/mouseout listeners like this:

```
$(".selector-selection").mouseover(function () {
    $(this).addClass("active-hover");
    polygons[$(this).attr("id")].setOptions({
        fillOpacity: 1
    });
});
$(".selector-selection").mouseleave(function () {
    $(this).removeClass("active-hover");
    polygons[$(this).attr("id")].setOptions({
        fillOpacity: 0.80
    });
});
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/cned9yod/6/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var map;
var polygons = [];

function initialize() {
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(45.509399, -73.631484);
  var mapOptions = {
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    styles: [{
      "featureType": "administrative",
      "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
      "stylers": [{
        "color": "#444444"
      }]
    }, {
      "featureType": "landscape",
      "elementType": "all",
      "stylers": [{
        "color": "#f2f2f2"
      }]
    }, {
      "featureType": "poi",
      "elementType": "all",
      "stylers": [{
        "visibility": "off"
      }]
    }, {
      "featureType": "road",
      "elementType": "all",
      "stylers": [{
        "saturation": -100
      }, {
        "lightness": 45
      }]
    }, {
      "featureType": "road.highway",
      "elementType": "all",
      "stylers": [{
        "visibility": "simplified"
      }]
    }, {
      "featureType": "road.highway",
      "elementType": "geometry.fill",
      "stylers": [{
        "visibility": "on"
      }, {
        "saturation": "0"
      }, {
        "lightness": "-17"
      }]
    }, {
      "featureType": "road.arterial",
      "elementType": "labels.icon",
      "stylers": [{
        "visibility": "off"
      }]
    }, {
      "featureType": "transit",
      "elementType": "all",
      "stylers": [{
        "visibility": "off"
      }]
    }, {
      "featureType": "water",
      "elementType": "all",
      "stylers": [{
        "color": "#171f4a"
      }, {
        "visibility": "on"
      }]
    }],
    center: latlng,
    zoom: 12
  };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('googleMappingContainer'), mapOptions);
  var griffintownSpec = [{
    lat: 45.498276,
    lng: -73.561388
  }, {
    lat: 45.490125,
    lng: -73.567316
  }, {
    lat: 45.485214,
    lng: -73.566365
  }, {
    lat: 45.492362,
    lng: -73.553377
  }, {
    lat: 45.494958,
    lng: -73.554621
  }, {
    lat: 45.495638,
    lng: -73.555167
  }, {
    lat: 45.496127,
    lng: -73.556017
  }, {
    lat: 45.498276,
    lng: -73.561388
  }];
  // Define the LatLng coordinates for the polygon's path.
  var cartiervilleSpec = [{
    lat: 45.584436,
    lng: -73.653354
  }, {
    lat: 45.575435,
    lng: -73.635593
  }, {
    lat: 45.564502,
    lng: -73.644627
  }, {
    lat: 45.554849,
    lng: -73.622688
  }, {
    lat: 45.550667,
    lng: -73.629578
  }, {
    lat: 45.549594,
    lng: -73.635563
  }, {
    lat: 45.527110,
    lng: -73.651303
  }, {
    lat: 45.532762,
    lng: -73.672160
  }, {
    lat: 45.530772,
    lng: -73.683041
  }, {
    lat: 45.528497,
    lng: -73.685711
  }, {
    lat: 45.528244,
    lng: -73.693001
  }, {
    lat: 45.522278,
    lng: -73.707653
  }, {
    lat: 45.525109,
    lng: -73.712272
  }, {
    lat: 45.523036,
    lng: -73.714220
  }, {
    lat: 45.526883,
    lng: -73.720741
  }, {
    lat: 45.521627,
    lng: -73.727325
  }, {
    lat: 45.523843,
    lng: -73.730999
  }, {
    lat: 45.520840,
    lng: -73.735133
  }, {
    lat: 45.515726,
    lng: -73.728039
  }, {
    lat: 45.508788,
    lng: -73.747975
  }, {
    lat: 45.504890,
    lng: -73.754049
  }, {
    lat: 45.510612,
    lng: -73.759969
  }, {
    lat: 45.512257,
    lng: -73.756549
  }, {
    lat: 45.512293,
    lng: -73.752671
  }, {
    lat: 45.516513,
    lng: -73.749149
  }, {
    lat: 45.517872,
    lng: -73.747108
  }, {
    lat: 45.518408,
    lng: -73.744658
  }, {
    lat: 45.525774,
    lng: -73.739248
  }, {
    lat: 45.527133,
    lng: -73.735268
  }, {
    lat: 45.529957,
    lng: -73.732818
  }, {
    lat: 45.530243,
    lng: -73.729909
  }, {
    lat: 45.535856,
    lng: -73.723581
  }, {
    lat: 45.537107,
    lng: -73.720519
  }, {
    lat: 45.537787,
    lng: -73.714139
  }, {
    lat: 45.539109,
    lng: -73.711434
  }, {
    lat: 45.544578,
    lng: -73.705361
  }, {
    lat: 45.547723,
    lng: -73.694286
  }, {
    lat: 45.547223,
    lng: -73.690102
  }, {
    lat: 45.549010,
    lng: -73.687141
  }, {
    lat: 45.549332,
    lng: -73.681783
  }, {
    lat: 45.555872,
    lng: -73.673515
  }, {
    lat: 45.561053,
    lng: -73.670657
  }, {
    lat: 45.565877,
    lng: -73.662185
  }, {
    lat: 45.578452,
    lng: -73.660552
  }, {
    lat: 45.580917,
    lng: -73.656571
  }, {
    lat: 45.584489,
    lng: -73.653509
  }];
  // Construct the polygon.
  var cartierville = new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: cartiervilleSpec,
    strokeColor: '#ffffff',
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 1,
    fillColor: '#DC3B35',
    fillOpacity: 0.80
  });
  cartierville.setMap(map);
  polygons["cartierville"] = cartierville;
  google.maps.event.addListener(cartierville, "mouseover", function() {
    this.setOptions({
      fillOpacity: "1"
    });
    $("#cartierville").addClass("active-hover");
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(cartierville, "mouseout", function() {
    this.setOptions({
      fillOpacity: "0.80"
    });
    $("#cartierville").removeClass("active-hover");
  });

  var griffintown = new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: griffintownSpec,
    strokeColor: '#ffffff',
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 1,
    fillColor: '#7FAFCB',
    fillOpacity: 0.80
  });
  griffintown.setMap(map);
  polygons["griffintown"] = griffintown;
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  for (var i = 0; i < griffintownSpec.length; i++) {
    bounds.extend(new google.maps.LatLng(griffintownSpec[i].lat, griffintownSpec[i].lng));
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < cartiervilleSpec.length; i++) {
    bounds.extend(new google.maps.LatLng(cartiervilleSpec[i].lat, cartiervilleSpec[i].lng));
  }
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
  google.maps.event.addListener(griffintown, "mouseover", function() {
    this.setOptions({
      fillOpacity: 1
    });
    $("#griffintown").addClass("active-hover");
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(griffintown, "mouseout", function() {
    this.setOptions({
      fillOpacity: 0.80
    });
    $("#griffintown").removeClass("active-hover");
  });

}

function codeAddress() {
  geocoder.geocode({
    'address': address
  }, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: results[0].geometry.location,
        map: map
      });

    } else {
      alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
    }
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
$(function() {
  $(".control-buttons div").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("step-complete");
  });

  $(".selector-selection").mouseover(function() {
    $(this).addClass("active-hover");
    polygons[$(this).attr("id")].setOptions({
      fillOpacity: 1
    });
  });
  $(".selector-selection").mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).removeClass("active-hover");
    polygons[$(this).attr("id")].setOptions({
      fillOpacity: 0.80
    });
  });
});
```

```css
html,
body,
#googleMappingContainer {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
.control-selector-group {
  height: 0;
  overflow: visible;
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  top: 80px;
}
.control-selector-location div {
  background: #ffffff;
  height: 46px;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0 0 2px 0;
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  line-height: 46px;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 0 20px;
}
.control-selector-location .selector-title h2 {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #18204a;
  line-height: 46px;
}
.control-selector-location .selector-selection {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: lighter;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.control-selector-location .selector-selection:hover {
  background: orange;
}
.active-hover#griffintown {
  background-color: #7FAFCB;
  color: #ffffff;
}
.active-hover#cartierville {
  background-color: #DC3B35;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<div class="selector-selection" class="element-to-hover" id="griffintown">GRIFFINTOWN</div>
<div class="selector-selection" id="cartierville">CARTIERVILLE</div>
<div id="googleMappingContainer"></div>
```